# Highlight multiple options in Cal Heatmap

Tags: javascript, cal-heatmap

I have an array of Javascript datetime objects which I want to display on a `cal-heatmap`. For this, i've done the following:

```
var startTimes = [] //array of datetimes to show
var cal = new CalHeatMap();
cal.init({
    itemSelector: '.heat-map',
    domain: 'day',
    subDomain: 'hour',
    range: range,
    start: new Date(startTimes[0]),
    highlight: new Date(startTimes[0])
});

for (s in startTimes) {
    cal.highlight(cal.options.highlight.push(new Date(startTimes[s])));
}
```

This however, doesn't seem to work as only the first date gets marked.

Comment: Could you review the answer and comment or accept it?

Answer (score 0):

Note that `push` returns the new length of the array and not the element you just added to it.

According to this and the doc of [cal-heatmap/#highlight](https://kamisama.github.io/cal-heatmap/#highlight) which states that the method expects a date, I guess your code should be:

```
for (s in startTimes) {
    var date = new Date(startTimes[s]);
    cal.options.highlight.push(date);
    cal.highlight(date);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to review this. What worked is adding the datetimeobjects into a single array and using those to show in the `data` parameter of the heatmap. :)